# Creating a file/folder structure and zipping it up?

Tags: php

I have a directory of image files and I need a php script or shell script that will rename them, create a structure of nested directories, and then insert each image into a specified place in the directory hierarchy. Ideally I would just specify a parent directory for each file and a parent directory for each directory and it would build it. And then finally, I need the script to zip up the whole thing.

There's probably not an existing php class that will do all this for me, but if anyone knows of a php class or other script available online that would handle a lot of this logic that would be great.

Comment: Why does it need to be PHP? You're doing file management- calling a shell script would likely be faster and easier.

Comment: A shell script would be fine. I just really only know PHP so my ability to modify a shell script may be limited.

Comment: In Windoze, I've done this kind of thing with a simple NT shell script (a/k/a batch file) and the 7-zip command-line exe. I can post a demo here if you need it...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm running a linux server.

Answer (score 1):

I know its not PHP, but you might want to investigate something like this:

a shell script for renaming files (your dialect may vary, but the man pages are very helpful).

```
foreach img (/path/to/directory/*.jpg)
  set newimg= `echo $img | sed 's,path/to/directory/(.+)\.jpg,new/path/$1newname.jpg/,'`
  cp img newimg
end
```

If all the files in a particular directory are going to one location, something like the above might work.  Essentially it loops through the target directory getting the names of the files that have a .jpg (or whatever) extension. Then it takes those names, including their path and subs in the new directory path and some change to the original file change. I've used `,` for the separator in the substitution because escaping all those path separators is a pain. Lastly, it copies the old file to the new location.

Since your directory needs are probably more complex than a hardcoded path allows for, you can include a line to parse your filepath/filename and determine what its target path should be; and use that in the substitution.

A snippet for creating a directory tree in one go can be found [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7216).

You may also decide that `find` is a better fit for this than `foreach` because it can descend a directory structure as far as you like.